# MongoDB filter and get count of all nested values

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I have a MongoDB collection with a schema like this:

```
{
   "_id":"0e5101cb8c39356305830f36",
   "person1":{
      "name":"Test",
      "status":"valid"
   },
   "person2":{
      "name":"Test2",
      "status":"invalid"
   },
   "person3":{
      "name":"Test3",
      "status":"valid"
   }
}
```

The `status` field can be either `valid`, `invalid` or `pending`. I want to query this collection and then count, for the whole collection, how many `valid`, `invalid` and `pending` persons it has. I am using a no-code tool to run a query so I think I need to use something like Aggregation Framework to process this. I am new to Aggregation framework, I tried a bunch of stages but couldn't make this work. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: That's an unusual data model.  Every document has 3 persons?  Why not one person per document?  Or if multiple persons are in a document, why not a `"persons"` array with `{"name": "jane", "status": "valid"}` object elements?  Yes, the aggregation is possible with your current model, but it will be unnecessarily complicated because of it.

Comment: @rickhg12hs yeah an unusual model. That's because I have no control over the schema but since it's a freelance client. I can try convincing him to use an Array for `persons` instead of doing it like that. But even with Arrays, how do I get the total count of, say `valid` persons?

Answer (score 0):

The data model is awkward (the first two stages below are just to get the data in a "reasonable" format), but here's one way you could do it.

```js
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    "$project": {
      "rootArray": {"$objectToArray": "$$ROOT"}
    }
  },
  {
    "$project": {
      "persons": {
        "$map": {
          "input": {
            "$filter": {
              "input": "$rootArray",
              "cond": {
                "$regexMatch": {
                  "input": "$$this.k",
                  "regex": "person"
                }
              }
            }
          },
          "as": "person",
          "in": "$$person.v"
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {"$unwind": "$persons"},
  {
    "$group": {
      "_id": "$persons.status",
      "count": {"$count": {} }
    }
  }
])
```

Try it on [mongoplayground.net](https://mongoplayground.net/p/4egLgOwXcO6).